# crear JDialog vacío al cambiar el evento

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy creando una pequeña aplicación en Java que calcule unas apuestas de manera automática.

Al pinchar sobre el botón resultados, se crea un `JDialog` de manera automática que muestra sobre un `textArea` la apuesta que se ha creado de manera automática y otra que también se crea automáticamente y hace de ganadora. En la misma interfaz del programa hay un botón estadística que al pinchar, se generan 1000 apuestas de manera automática y se comparan con una ganadora también generada de manera aleatoria.

El problema lo tengo, en que uso el `JDialog` para ambas cosas, y si creo una estadística antes de pinchar sobre el botón resultados, me muestra los 1000 resultados(hasta ahí bien). Pero si después pincho sobre resultados, se me vuelve a abrir el mismo `JDialog` con dichos resultados. Y lo que pretendo es que, aunque sea el mismo `JDialog`, se limpie para cada acción.

Adjunto código hasta ahora de los `ActionListener`:

```
resultadosBt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(resultadosBt.getText() == "Resultados"){

                resultados = new Resultados(apuestas, apuesta, "Resultados", ventana);
            }
        }
    }); 

estadisticaBt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(estadisticaBt.getText() == "Estadistica"){
                contador = 0;
                while(contador < 1000){
                    generaApuestaAutomatica();
                    contador++;
                }
                resultados = new Resultados(apuestas, apuesta, "Estadistica", ventana);
            }
        }
    });
```

Esta es la interfaz, para que os hagáis una idea:

[image: interfaz]

Cuando pincho sobre estadística, se crean las 1000 apuestas y se compara con una ganadora y todo se muestra en un `JDialog`:

[image: JDialog]

Cuando pincho sobre resultados debería de aparecerme vacío, a no ser que yo le dé al botón de automática, que entonces va almacenando las apuestas y me las mostraría en resultados.

Comment: Alguien me puede echar una mano?? Gracias por adelantado